# Run a useEffect only once when met a certain condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to run multiple functions inside useEffect hook. I want the functions to run after the isConnected value is resolved to a value. Its initial value is null. after a moment it will resolve into true or false. I'm considering only the first time the isConnected value is changed. The value can change over time. I have written the following code for achieving this. I want to know if is this the correct way to achieve my goal and if there are any refactors I can do to simplify this.

```
const App = () => {

    const {isConnected} = useNetInfo();

    const wasConnectedRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isConnected !== null && wasConnectedRef.current === null) {
            if (isConnected) {
                functionOne();
                functionTwo();
            }
            wasConnectedRef.current = isConnected;
        }
    }, [isConnected]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, a refactor would be to make a custom hook called something like `useIsConnected` but that would only be worth it if you where going to use this hook in multiple Components, also you might need to add `functionOne` and `functionTwo` as a dependency depending on if they have state

Answer (score 1):

I would add another useState variable that you set to true once the data has been fetched and add that as a listener in the square brackets at the end of your useEffect